# Jenkins SVN, run Ant task only on the tag that has been updated

Tags: svn, ant, jenkins, tags

I have defined a Jenkins build that polls and retrieves all SVN tags from a specific folder. If a new tag is created, Jenkins downloads it. However, I also need to build the Java application using Ant in that tag folder. How can can execute the Ant target only for that new (or updated) tag folder and not for the existing unchanged tags folders?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **List Subversion tag (and more)** parameter? It's great for manual builds, but unfortunately, for automated/polled builds, you need to explicitly state which tag to use. Would be great if it could use the sorting order to determine a new tag for automated builds.